# having problem writing trigger for custom objects where if i save a recrd in negotiations it should be saved to other custom object player

Tags: trigger

i have negotiations as a custom object with 2 record types
sales negotiation &
purchase negotiation

i want to write a trigger such that if i save any player name in purchase negotiation it should be saved to my other custom object Player and deleted from custom object Favourites,which has a lookup relationship with Negotiation object.

This was the code i was trying to write,but getting error 
"Error: Compile Error: Invalid type: Player at line 4 column 31"'

```
public with sharing class CreatePlayerFromNegotiations {
public  void CreatePlayer ( List<Negotiation__c> negosFromTrigger) {
Account negoAcct = [Select a.Id From Account a where a.Name ='Purchase Negotiation'];
List<Player> pList = new List<Player>();
for (Negotiation__c currentNegotiation : negosFromTrigger) {
Player p = new Player();
p.PlayerName = currentNegotiation.Name_Of_Player__c ;
pList.add(p);

}
Database.insert(pList);
}
}
```

please help.

Comment: Why did you query `Account negoAcct`. I don't see any use of it

Comment: i am new to triggers was trying to write after taking reference from varoius examples.

Comment: Anyway `Player` should be `Player__c`. Check its API name.

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger would look like this:

```
public with sharing class CreatePlayerFromNegotiations 
{
    public  void CreatePlayer ( List<Negotiation__c> negosFromTrigger) 
    {
        // Don't know why I queried???
        Account negoAcct = [Select a.Id From Account a where a.Name ='Purchase Negotiation'];
        List<Player__c> pList = new List<Player__c>();
        for (Negotiation__c currentNegotiation : negosFromTrigger) 
        {
            // Use API name not the Label
            Player__c p = new Player__c();
            p.PlayerName = currentNegotiation.Name_Of_Player__c ;
            pList.add(p);
        }
        Database.insert(pList);
    }
}
```

Also use `Player` object **API name** not the Label (Player). API names have suffix `__c`

Comment: still getting the same error.the error is in

Comment: List<Player> pList = new List<Player>();

Comment: @d.dub Change it as well to List<Player__c> pList = new List<Player__c>();

Comment: I updated the answer to include the "__c".